# Android - deep link - got null categories from intent

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking, deeplink

My app can be opened with deep link. When clicking a link in an email from the Outlook Android app, my app is opened. But, the `Intent` doesn't contain any categories. In my activity, `getIntent().getCategories()` returns `null`.

The same link works fine in the Gmail app on the same device. The app is opened and `getIntent().getCategories()` returns a list with `Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE` in it.

Does it mean when a app is opened from deep link, it doesn't always get category in the `Intent`?

Answer (score 0):

Check out that you getting `getIntent()` onResume

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(getIntent() != null){
       // do something
    }
}
```

if still no luck, then check onNewIntent

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if(intent != null){
       // do something
    }
}
```

I had the same issue, and totally forgot about overriding the `onNewIntent` method in the activity.